# Sort std::vector<myclass> in one line using sort function from STL

Tags: c++, stl

Question is about sorting `std::vector<myclass>` using function `sort` from STL's algorithms class.
Standard way is : `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), &myfunct)`
where `myfunct` is:

```
bool myfunct( myclass first, myclass second ) {   
    if (first.value < second.value)   
        return true;   
    else return false;   
}
```

Approach above takes more than one line. I am curious how to do it in one line. Is it possible define function that compares myclass objects inside sort function? May be somehow use this `(a < b) ? a : b`. I remember that there is something like this in C#, but I forgot how is it called. Is it possible to do in C++.

Comment: `return first.value < last.value;`

Comment: or define `operator<` in myclass and call `sort(v.begin(), v.end())`

Comment: If you're using C++11 then you can look at passing a lambda function I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First,  you can just return `first.value < second.value` but this doesn't get rid of the function. In C++2011 you can use a lambda function:

```
   std::sort(begin, end, [](myclass const& f, myclass const& s){ return f.value < s.value; });
```

Without C++2011 I think you'll need a function object because there isn't anything which projects your class to the value you actually want to compare.

BTW, you definitely want to pass everything but the most trivial objects by reference to your comparison function.

Comment: by value? i'm sure you meant by reference.

Answer (score 2):

**You could use `boost::lambda` and `boost::lambda::bind` (with boost lambda placeholders)**

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            boost::lambda::bind(&A::a, boost::lambda::_1)
            <
            boost::lambda::bind(&A::a, boost::lambda::_2));
```

`sort` passes 2 values to the comparison function so you need to compare those 2 values. The bind part of code just selects variable `a` from the `struct A` from each structures being compared (referenced by `_1` and `_2`).

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

struct A
{
    A() : a(0), b(0) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, A & a)
{ return os << a.a << ":" << a.b; }
```

---

```
int main()
{
    boost::array<A,5> vec;
    std::fill(vec.begin(),vec.end(),A());

    vec[0].a = 1;
    vec[1].a = 3;
    vec[2].a = 4;
    vec[3].a = 0;
    vec[4].a = 2;

    std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << ' ');
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            boost::lambda::bind(&A::a, boost::lambda::_1)
            <
            boost::lambda::bind(&A::a, boost::lambda::_2));

    std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << ' ');
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1:0 3:0 4:0 0:0 2:0 
0:0 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:0
```

Answer (score 1):

why not copy the vector into a set:

```
std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::inserter(s,s.end()));
```

Now the elements in the set are sorted  in ascending order and use set now.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner call to sort() :  `sort(my_vector_of_class_object.begin(),my_vector_of_class_object.end(),compare);`

Code of a working demo of a  "*sort vector of class objects*" is  provided below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class my_Class
{

    public:

    my_Class(int r,int n, int s):rollno(r),name(n),status(s) { }
    int getRollno() const { return rollno;}
    int getName() const { return name;}
    int getStatus() const { return status;}

    private:

    int rollno;
    int name;
    int status;
    };

    bool compare(const my_Class& x, const my_Class& y) {
    return x.getRollno() < y.getRollno();
}

int main()
{
    vector<my_Class> my_vector_of_class_object;
    vector<my_Class>::const_iterator iter;

    my_Class s1(10,20,30);
    my_Class s2(40,50,60);
    my_Class s3(25,85,9);

    my_Class s4(1,50,2);
    my_Class s5(90,70,90);
    my_Class s6(85,85,3);

    my_Class s7(20,6,89);
    my_Class s8(70,54,22);
    my_Class s9(65,22,77);


    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s1);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s2);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s3);

    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s4);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s5);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s6);


    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s7);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s8);
    my_vector_of_class_object.push_back(s9);



    cout <<"Before vector sort \n";

    for(iter=my_vector_of_class_object.begin(); iter!=my_vector_of_class_object.end();++iter)
    std::cout << (*iter).getRollno() << '\t' << (*iter).getName() << '\t' << (*iter).getStatus() << '\n';
    cout <<"  \n\n";

    sort(my_vector_of_class_object.begin(),my_vector_of_class_object.end(),compare);


    cout <<"After vector sort \n";

    for(iter=my_vector_of_class_object.begin(); iter!=my_vector_of_class_object.end();++iter)
    std::cout << (*iter).getRollno() << '\t' << (*iter).getName() << '\t' << (*iter).getStatus() << '\n';

    cout <<"  \n\n";


return 0;
}
```