# Sorting in C++ using defined class

Tags: c++

I'm kind of new at C++, so bear with me if you can. I'm trying to sort a vector full of nodes. In my .h file I have the following definition for a node:

```
class Node{
public:
    Node(int data);
    bool sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2);
    int getData();

private:
    int nData;
};
```

In my .cpp file, I define the functions such as:

```
Node::Node(int data){
    this->nData = data;
}
bool Node::sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2){
    return n1.nData < n2.nData;
}
```

and in main attempt to sort a vector with:

```
Node aNode(7);
Node bNode(90);
Node cNode(84);
std::vector<Node> arrayName;
arrayName.push_back(aNode);
arrayName.push_back(bNode);
arrayName.insert(arrayName.begin(), cNode);
std::sort(arrayName.begin(), arrayName.end(), &Node::sortMe);
```

I include algorithm and everything, I just can't figure out why it doesn't want to use that function to sort the data...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are tons of dupes scattered across SO, but non-static member functions have a hidden `this` parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675619/sort-stdvectormyclass-in-one-line-using-sort-function-from-stl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sortMe()` is currently declared as a member function. That means it needs to be called on a specific instance of the `Node` class, rather than being used as a standalone function.

To fix it, simply prefix the function declaration with `static` (only in the class header; not in the implementation). That means the function belongs to the class, not a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html):

```
std::sort( arrayName.begin(), arrayName.end(),
                                         boost::bind(&Node::sortMe, this,_1,_2));
```

or make `sortMe` function static.
Even better is to use a functor instead of a function (this will be faster):

```
class Node{
public:
    Node(int data);
    bool sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2);
    int getData();
    struct doCompare
    { 
       bool operator()( const Node& n1, const Node& n2  )
       { 
            // comparison code
       }
    };

private:
    int nData;
};

std::sort( arrayName.begin(), arrayName.end(), Node::doCompare() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `std::sort()` need **a reference of comparison function**.

There will be two ways to implement the comparison function:

- **static member function**
  A normal member function shall not be used since a member function must need a specific instance of its class.

> class Node{
>
> public:
>
> **static** bool sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2);
>
> };

- **normal function()**.
  Remove the 'bool sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2);' out from the Node class to the main.cpp, the problem will be solved.

> bool Node::sortMe(const Node & n1, const Node & n2){
>
> ```
>    return n1.nData < n2.nData;
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++11, you can use lambda.

```
std::sort(arrayName.begin(), arrayName.end(), [](Node& l, Node& r){ return l.getData() < r.getData(); });
```